# How can i automatically run every file with .osz format when there are downloaded

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to automatically run every .osz file when its downloaded.

There used for a game and i need to manuely start everyone after another  when i want to add the files to my gamefiels (By starting the file it automaticly installs the files tot he game folder).
It takes 2  seconds usually to add the files so i addet an delay of 5 seconds.

There are downloaded at `C:\Users\MushroomFX\Downloads\Chrome`  .

Im using this:

```
@echo off

cd C:\Users\MushroomFX\Downloads\Chrome



cls



:st

start *.osz

timeout 5

goto st
```

but it doesnt work

Also if I rename the file to Test.osz and do start `Test.osz` it works. So i think that its executable. But it wont start with start `*.osz`. Or do i need an external `.vbs` file for it to work?

Pls help

Comment: If you cannot use the wildcard, you'll need to determine the files names first. You could do that with a [tag:for-loop]. You've already asked this question previously, so should have already had time to use the search facility. Please use it to find some [[tag:for-loop]] examples.

Comment: `for %%i in (*.osz) do start "" "%%~i"`

Comment: Thank you Gerhard for the command. It works an everything is fine. Sorry for not answering for so long. I couldnt test the command in the last time because i had no time in the last days. I have one last question how can i close the programm after starting every file? When I just type ```else exit``` in the next line it doesnt close (im new to this). so can you tell me wat else is in batch? :D

Comment: Me've already figured it out :)